# Retrieve datetime value from SQL Server table using C# Sql Reader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am querying a SQL Server table to get a value that is of the datatype `datetime` in the table.

The item in the database is this: `2014-05-17 23:52:09.333`

The following code throws this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.

Code:

```
internal List<string> CustomSqlQuery(string dbName, string dbTable, string dbColumn, string query, string connString)
{
        var databaseItems = new List<string>();
        var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        try
        {
            using (cmd)
            {
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // exception thrown on the following line
                        // Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.
                        var item = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(dbColumn));
                        databaseItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Log(Loglevel.Error, "Boom: {0}", exception.Message);
            return null;
        }
        return databaseItems;
    }
```

How do you convert the `datetime` into a string?

Comment: This code is broken at a fundamental level. It forces you to build queries in a way that will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Joel How do you make this example less vulnerable to SQL injection? Is it just a few things? I'll read about it and see how to do that.

Comment: Hard to know where to start with this. It's a bad idea anyway, but at least return a list of object, seeing as this function has no idea how the data is typed.

Comment: To avoid the security issue, the function also needs to ask for a collection containing parameter information, so that you can build a parameterized query.

Comment: Table name can't be a parameter. By the time you've finished really securing something like this, you might as well have said stuff it and  just used linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That column is typed to be a datetime, so you have to retrieve it using `GetDateTime` method call.

If you want all values to be retrieved as `string`, not matter what is the correct type in database, you can do it with `GetValue` and `ToString` method call:

```
var item = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(dbColumn)).ToString();
```

However, you should be aware that it may throw an exception, when one of the values is `null`. To avoid that, use following:

```
var value = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(dbColumn));
var item = value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString();
```

Comment: If this is a solution, then you need to change the name of your function to CustomSQLQueryThatOnlyDealsWithADateColumn

Comment: Using `GetValue` will let you deal with all types, and returns string representation of value.

Comment: Saw GetDateTime at top didn't notice GetValue. Course returning dates as strings gives me the heebies...